# Entity Framework 7: How do I update my database with only a specific migration?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm having some issues updating my database to reflect my model changes using migrations in EF7. At first, I create a model (let's just say Person for example), created an initial migration, and updated my database.

```
dnx ef migrations add Initial
dnx ef database update
```

No problems there, everything worked fine. However, now I'm creating another model (let's say "Car") that I also want to create a table for. So I followed the same steps: add a new migration, and try updating my database using dnx like below.

```
dnx ef migrations add CreateCarTable
dnx ef database update CreateCarTable
```

This is where I get my problems. Even though I'm specifying the specific migration I want to use, it keeps trying to run all of them, so I'm getting an error complaining that tables already exist (in my case it's the AspNetRoles tables that gets created in the "Initial" migration).

Has anyone had similar problems and/or have a solution to this?

Comment: Mmmm, The table already exists? Do you have the script for `Initial`? Maybe this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/988763/Database-Migration-in-Entity-Framework) helps you.

Comment: Try doing a dnx ef migrations script -Idempotent and see why it doesn't recognize the first migration as being run already.